# Помогите оптимизировать программу по времени работы (600мс)

Tags: python, оптимизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Гоблины Мглистых гор очень любях ходить к своим шаманам. Так как гоблинов много, к шаманам часто образуются очень длинные очереди. А поскольку много гоблинов в одном месте быстро
образуют шумную толку, которая мешает шаманам проводить сложные медицинские манипуляции,
последние решили установить некоторые правила касательно порядка в очереди.
Обычные гоблины при посещении шаманов должны вставать в конец очереди. Привилегированные же гоблины, знающие особый пароль, встают ровно в ее середину, причем при нечетной длине
очереди они встают сразу за центром.
Так как гоблины также широко известны своим непочтительным отношением ко всяческим правилам и законам, шаманы попросили вас написать программу, которая бы отслеживала порядок
гоблинов в очереди.
Формат входных данных
В первой строке входных данный записано число N (1 <N <10**5
) − количество запросов.
Следующие N строк содержат описание запросов в формате:

• + i − гоблин с номером i (1 <i <N) встаёт в конец очереди.

• * i − привилегированный гоблин с номером i встает в середину очереди.

• - − первый гоблин из очереди уходит к шаманам. Гарантируется, что на момент такого запроса
очередь не пуста.

Формат выходных данных
Для каждого запроса типа - программа должна вывести номер гоблина, который должен зайти
к шаманам

```
import collections

num = int(input())

newList = collections.deque()

el = ''

mun = []

while (num):
    var = str(input())
    if var[0] == '+':

        newList.append(int(var[1:10000]))
    elif var[0] == '-':
        print(newList.popleft())
    else:
        flag = len(newList) // 2
        if len(newList) % 2 == 0:
            newList.insert((flag), int(var[1:]))
        else:
            newList.insert(((flag) + 1), int(var[1:]))
num -= 1
```

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: Текст задачи верните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша программа работает медленно потому что вставка элемента в середину очереди требует линейного времени - надо скопировать половину элементов очереди чтобы освободить место в середине для нового элемента.

Подсказка: если будете хранить две очереди примерно равного размера, вставка в середину будет занимать константу. Остальные операции тоже можно доработать так чтобы они остались константными.

Например:

```
import collections


q1 = collections.deque()
q2 = collections.deque()
for _ in range(int(input())):

    c = input().split()

    if c[0] == '+':
        q2.append(c[1])
    elif c[0] == '*':
        q2.appendleft(c[1])
    else:
        print(q1.popleft())

    if len(q1) < len(q2):
        q1.append(q2.popleft())
```

Comment: Идея понятна,спасибо  большое...

Comment: Вы не могли показать,как это должно работать?(можно на "пальцах")

Comment: Спасибо большое,так понятнее...